# Make dropdown mandatory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop-down generated by a backoffice. I cannot change how this drop-down is coded by the backoffice. But I need to make  user selection mandatory for this dropdown.

I am using the following code and this works in the [**JSFIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jomcv57r/36/). However, this code sees if the user chooses another value than value "A" to determine if a selection is made. But this in not good enough in my situation because this value indication changes in other drop-downs.
I need the code to see if the user choice has changed from the text "PLEASE SELECT - $0,00" The "- $0,00" may also vary in different drop-downs, so I need the code to only filter on the "PLEASE SELECT" part of the drop-down text.

Also I need the browser to not ask to turn these warnings off in this case.

Can anyone help please?

```
function selection()
{    
 var cat = document.getElementById('select').value;    
    if (cat == "A") {

            alert('Please make a selection');
            return false;
   }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You cannot control how a browser displays an `alert`. If you need fine control over that, roll your own dialog (or use one of the thousands available)

Comment: replace the alert with a modal test if the value is not the first elements value

Comment: how would I do the modal test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there is couple of questions in your question, lets start with

1) Ensuring the selected item does not start with "PLEASE SELECT".

```
function selection()
{    
    var sel = document.getElementById('select');    
    var selectedText = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
    if (selectedText.startsWith("PLEASE SELECT")) {

            alert('Please make a selection');
            return false;
   }
    return true;
}
```

2) Stopping the user forcing the browser to no longer allow `alert`

This is not something you can control. If you want full control over a model dialog then there are plenty of these available - bootstrap has one, jQueryUI has one. Any UI framework you're using will almost certainly have one

Comment: Thank you! Your code works great in the JSFIDDLE. But when I apply it to the website it isn't working for my Tour Dates drop-down. Clearly I am doing something wrong. Did change the ID.  Please, see here: http://www.photographycoursetour.com/japan-photo-tour-photography-course.html

Comment: "please see <my entire website>" - really? You're expecting me to find exactly what you're having trouble with?

Comment: sorry, thought you may be able to zoom in on the code of the drop down. I will post some code in a JSFIDDLE.

Comment: @Eddy I did, but I cant see any specific problem. But you didnt tell me what problem you were having - only that it "isnt working"

Comment: The problem is that when the user does make a choice for a Tour Date that no warning hereof is given in an alert. Please see JS FIDDLE here: https://jsfiddle.net/u8zhhxpL/1/

Comment: You were never calling your `selection()` method. See update: https://jsfiddle.net/u8zhhxpL/2/ (added `onsubmit="return selection()"` to your form.)

Comment: Yes, this works in the JSFIDDLE. Thanks!!  Is there a way to add the onsubmit="return selection()" with a script? As the form is generated by backoffice software that I cannot get onsubmit="return selection()" added to it.

Answer (score 4):

Alert whatever text you want in a span instead of using `alert()`

```
document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Please make a selection";
```

Check the updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jomcv57r/37/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
function selection()
{    
 var cat = $('#select option:selected').val();    
    if (cat == $('#select option:first-child').val()) {

            alert('Please make a selection');
            return false;
   }
    return true;
}
```

For the warnings you will need to change you alert to a modal or on the page as a notice/warning message

Comment: Surely you want `text()` not `val()`

Comment: @Jamiec why is that?

Comment: I missed that you were comparing values - this also works of course. The OP actually specified they want any option which starts "PLEASE SELECT". While this doesnt do *exactly* what they asked, I agree that it has much the same end result.